# Form theme for "sonata_type_datetime_picker" not loaded in sonata admin

Tags: datepicker, twig, sonata-admin, symfony-3.3

I am using Sonata Admin with some fields of the type `DateTime` and I want to use `sonata_type_datetime_picker` as described [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html). This worked very well a few days ago, but now it stopped working and I have no idea, why. Spend nearly a day on this now with no progress.

`twig.yml`:

```
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    form_themes:
        - 'SonataCoreBundle:Form:datepicker.html.twig'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
```

Usage in my admin class:

```
->add(
    'creationDate',
    'sonata_type_datetime_picker',
    [
        'required' => false
    ]
)
```

But it is rendered like this (so I think the `form_theme` is not loaded at all since it kinda fallbacks to `sonata-ba-field-standard-natural`?)

```
<div class="form-group" id="sonata-ba-field-container-s59c611aaec3a3_creationDate">
    <label class=" control-label" for="s59c611aaec3a3_creationDate">
        Erstelldatum
    </label>
    <div class="sonata-ba-field sonata-ba-field-standard-natural">
        <input type="text" id="s59c611aaec3a3_creationDate" name="s59c611aaec3a3[creationDate]" class="sonata-medium-date form-control" value="20.09.2017, 15:41:43"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

My `twig.yml` is definitely loaded since it crashes when I add some errors. But when I modify `datepicker.html.twig` directly in the vendor folder by misspelling some twig code, nothing crashes - even when I delete the cache folder by myself.

Does anyone have a clue what possibly could be wrong or where I could start to dig even deeper? Bundle versions:

```
"php":                                      "7.0.*",
"symfony/symfony":                          "3.3.*",
"api-platform/core":                        "^2.0",
"doctrine/orm":                             "^2.5",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle":                 "^1.6",
"doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle":           "^1.2",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle":               "^2.3",
"symfony/monolog-bundle":                   "^3.0",
"sensio/distribution-bundle":               "^5.0",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle":            "^3.0.2",
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler":     "^2.0",
"dunglas/action-bundle":                    "^0.3",
"nelmio/cors-bundle":                       "^1.4",
"phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock":        "^3.0",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle":              "^3.21",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle":             "~2.0",
"doctrine/data-fixtures":                   "^1.2",
"nelmio/api-doc-bundle":                    "^2.11.2",
"sonata-project/intl-bundle":               "^2.3",
"knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle":             "~0.4",
"sonata-project/user-bundle":               "dev-add_support_for_fos_user2"
```

**Update**: Does also not work with symfony 3.2:

```
"php":                                      "7.0.*",
"symfony/symfony":                          "3.2.*",
"api-platform/core":                        "^2.0",
"doctrine/orm":                             "^2.5",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle":                 "^1.6",
"doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle":           "^1.2",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle":               "^2.3",
"symfony/monolog-bundle":                   "^3.0",
"sensio/distribution-bundle":               "^5.0",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle":            "^3.0.2",
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler":     "^2.0",
"dunglas/action-bundle":                    "^0.3",
"nelmio/cors-bundle":                       "^1.4",
"phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock":        "^3.0",
"sonata-project/admin-bundle":              "^3.21",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle":             "~2.0",
"doctrine/data-fixtures":                   "^1.2",
"nelmio/api-doc-bundle":                    "^2.11.2",
"sonata-project/intl-bundle":               "^2.3",
"knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle":             "~0.4",
"sonata-project/user-bundle":               "dev-add_support_for_fos_user2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. For some reason, `SonataUserBundle` requires the (obsolete?) parameter `twig.form.resources`. So I just added `twig.form.resources: []` into my `parameters.yml` to workaround this.

But for some reason, this completely overwrote my twig configuration:

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'SonataCoreBundle:Form:datepicker.html.twig'
```

So as a workaround, I now do also this:

```
twig.form.resources: ['SonataCoreBundle:Form:datepicker.html.twig']
```